# WebApi return 404 on server for PUT

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

After reading several similar questions and trying their solution, none worked for me.

I have this controller with the same route for `get`, `post` and `put`. The 3 work perfectly locally, but deployed on the server, `PUT` returns me a 404.

Here's the code for the controller actions. All obfuscated because, its code I'm developing for a client

```
[Route("objects/")]
[Route("objects/{token}/")]
[Route("controller/objects/")]
[Route("controller/objects/{token}/")]
[ActionName("objects")]
[HttpGet()]
public List<Object> Objects(string token)
{
    // Works perfectly, both local and deployed
}
[Route("objects/")]
[Route("objects/{token}/")]
[Route("controller/objects/")]
[Route("controller/objects/{token}/")]
[ActionName("objects")]
[HttpPost()]
public string InsertObjects([FromUri]string token, [FromBody]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject obj)
{
     // Returns a 500, but at least its called. Not used for the moment
}
[Route("objects/")]
[Route("controller/objects/")]
[ActionName("objects")]
[HttpPut()]
public string RemoveObject([FromBody]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject obj)
{
    // Returns a 404 deployed on server. Works perfectly locally
    // If you wonder why put instead of delete for a remove action, its because we don't delete from the db, just set a field value to false
}
```

I have been reading that, it might be that the PUT handler is not on the config, but this is the current handler

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

As you can see, `verb` is set to `*`, which means it should also consider `PUT` and `DELETE`, right?

Comment: Disable the WebDAV module.

Comment: Wow, didn't saw that one! thanks, will try this, and report back, will take some time, as this servers is managed by the client and the client's it personal must do this

Comment: In 99% of cases, this is the culprit. If not, please show what other things you have tried. "ASP.NET WebApi 404" gives a _lot_ of Stack Overflow hits on Google already.

Comment: Well, in the end, this wasn't the solution. After getting a little talk with the admins of the server, I found out that the firewall was the one not letting `PUT` and `DELETE` methods go through. So I had to write my own message handler and do a Method Override with the header `X-HTTP-Method-Override`. So I'm sending a `POST`with this header when a `PUT` is due. More about this strategy on this [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx)